# ASP.NET Web Api HttpPost Task returning a 204 instead of 201

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET Web Api and one of the methods is exposed as a POST operation.  It works fine, but it returns a HTTP Result of 204 instead of 201 as expected.  Here is the method definition:

```
[HttpPost][ActionName("Save")]
public Task SaveGameState(Guid instanceId, [FromBody] ComparisonGameState state)
{
    return gameInstancesClient.SaveGameState(instanceId, state);
}
```

Is the fact that it is returning a Task confusing Web Api?

I could do the following instead, but it seems like overkill:

```
[HttpPost][ActionName("Save")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SaveGameState(Guid instanceId, [FromBody] ComparisonGameState state)
{
    await gameInstancesClient.SaveGameState(instanceId, state);
    return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created };
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring further input, this seems to be the only workable solution:

```
[HttpPost][ActionName("Save")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SaveGameState(Guid instanceId, [FromBody] ComparisonGameState state)
{
    await gameInstancesClient.SaveGameState(instanceId, state);
    return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Task type in your action definition to Task of HttpResponseMessage. Internally, WebAPI treats a non-generic Task as if you were returning void, so it sends back a 204. If your task returns an HttpResponseMessage, make sure you change the return type to Task of HttpResponseMessage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So are you saying to do what I typed as the 2nd example in the post?  It seems like it *should* be unnecessary.  If it knows it is an HttpPost and it doesn't throw an exception, it should return a HttpStatusCode.Created yes?  Or do you have to make that explicit.

Comment: No Arash. I assumed that your method SaveGameState returns a Task of HttpResponseMessage. In that case, all you have to do is change the method signature to match.

Comment: Hi Youssef, I am completely confused by what you are recommending.  As I said, the first code snippet I posted *should* work but returns a 204 (which is incorrect behavior).  The 2nd more verbose snippet works 100% ok but I would like to not have to do it the verbose way.