# DeleteAsync and PostAsync not working

Tags: c#, mvvm, async-await, mvvm-light

I wrote this working PutAsync, which lets me update items in my database:

```
private async void Edit()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        Item i = new Item();
        i.ID = SelectedItem.ID;
        i.Name = SelectedItem.Name;
        i.Cost = SelectedItem.Cost;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(i);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync("http://localhost:5065/api/item", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string jsonresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            int result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(jsonresponse);
            if (result == 2)
            {
                GetItems();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to delete items and add new items, but this code doesn't seem to work:

```
public ICommand DeleteCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(Delete); }
}

private async void Delete()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        Item i = new Item();
        i.ID = SelectedItem.ID;
        i.Name = SelectedItem.Name;
        i.Cost = SelectedItem.Cost;

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.DeleteAsync("http://localhost:5065/api/item/" + i.ID );
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string jsonresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            int result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(jsonresponse);
            if (result == 2)
            {
                GetItems();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the same goes for my PostAsync:

```
private async void New()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {     
        Item i = new Item();
        i.Name = SelectedItem.Name;
        i.Cost = SelectedItem.Cost;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(i);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5065/api/item", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string jsonresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            int result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(jsonresponse);
            if (result == 2)
            {
                GetItems();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following response:

```
{StatusCode: 204, ReasonPhrase: 'No Content', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:{  Pragma: no-cache  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcU0NIT09MXE5NQ1QgTGFhdHN0ZVxCdXNpbmVzcyBhcHBsaWNhdGlvbnNcUFJPSkVDVFxQcm9qZWN0XFByb2plY3QuYXBpXGFwaVxwcm9kdWN0XDU=?=  Cache-Control: no-cache  Date: Mon, 19 Jan 2015 13:48:32 GMT  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET  Expires: -1}}
```

What did I do wrong and how can I make both my post and delete work?

EDIT:
Here's some serverside code of the Delete void, it's pretty Basic:

```
public static int DeleteItem(int id)
        {
            int rowsaffected = 0;
            DbTransaction trans = null;

            try
            {
                trans = Database.BeginTransaction("ConnectionString");

                string sql = "DELETE FROM Item WHERE ID=@ID";
                DbParameter par1 = Database.AddParameter("ConnectionString", "@ID", id);
                rowsaffected += Database.ModifyData(trans, sql, par1);

                trans.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (trans != null)
                    trans.Rollback();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (trans != null)
                    Database.ReleaseConnection(trans.Connection);
            }

            return rowsaffected;
        }
```

I call it here:

```
   // DELETE: api/Item/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            ItemDataAccess.DeleteItem(id);
        }
```

EDIT:
Maybe some extra info, on the following line

```
int result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(jsonresponse);
```

I get this error in both cases:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: No JSON content found and type 'System.Int32' is not nullable. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

Comment: You need to show how these methods are being called. `async void` methods should only be used in very specific circumstances (e.g. event handlers).

Comment: If you send a delete to your server via `PostMan` or some other REST client, does it work? In other words, are you sure your server is processing the request right?

Comment: What's your server-side code?

Comment: When you debug your server are you actually getting into your code, or is it failing out earlier in the pipeline.

Comment: @SteveMitcham I am getting into the code, then I get a 204 and nothing is changed

Answer (score 1):

Your calls are successful,  204 is a success code that is telling the client not to expect any data in the body.  You aren't returning anything from your messages so the server is auto filling in 204 for the `void` type on the Controller Method.

Comment: I don't know if that's it, I've tried setting it to `public int Delete(int id)
        {
           return ItemDataAccess.DeleteItem(id);
        }` And it still doesn't change anything in my database, I still get the 204 No Content response though

Comment: If you want to return a value, check out this question that may end up being a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370196/asp-net-web-api-httppost-task-returning-a-204-instead-of-201